# Twilio using a local number I already have

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

Hi I have a local landline number and a mobile number, is it possible for twilio to make outgoing call thru the Mobile number or landline number I already have ? So that way customers call us back to our office number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. Twilio can make the callerid show up as any number you have verified, but the actual call will be made by another number for billing purposes.

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-i-use-a-non-twilio-number-as-the-caller-id-for-outgoing-calls

> **Can I use a non-Twilio number as the caller ID for outgoing calls?**
>
> Yes, just verify the number with Twilio. Verification takes just a few
>   seconds, and proves to us that you have authority to use the phone
>   number. Sorry, no prank calls from your bro’s phone number! Once the
>   phone number has been verified, it can be used with the ‘callerID’
>   attribute for your outbound calls.

Comment: And how do you connect to the landline or mobile number ? Thru wires or its automatically done by the cloud ?

Comment: The call gets initiated by Twilio thru code you write, but it looks as if it comes from your verified number.